Why is Angular asking for an standalone component, even though it is
Pretty much what the title says, I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code for circulo.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Circulo } from '../figura-geometrica';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-circulo',
  templateUrl: './circulo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./circulo.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
})
export class CirculoComponent extends Circulo implements OnInit {

  override radio: number = 0;

  constructor(nombre:string, radio:number) {
    super(nombre, radio)
    this.radio = radio;
  }

   ngOnInit() {}

   override calcularPerimetro(): number {
    return this.radio * 2 * 3.1416
  }


}

This is what it's importing on the second line from circulo.component.ts, figura-geometrica.ts:
export abstract class FiguraGeometrica {
    nombre : string = "";

    constructor(nombre:string) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    abstract calcularPerimetro(): number
}

export class Circulo extends FiguraGeometrica {
    radio : number = 0;

    constructor(nombre:string, radio:number) {
        super(nombre)
        this.radio = radio;
    }
    override calcularPerimetro(): number {
        return this.radio * 2 * 3.1416
    }
}

export class TrianguloEscaleno extends FiguraGeometrica {

    ladoA : number = 0;
    ladoB : number = 0;
    ladoC : number = 0;

    constructor(nombre:string, ladoA:number, ladoB:number, ladoC:number) {
        super(nombre)
        this.ladoA = ladoA;
        this.ladoB = ladoB;
        this.ladoC = ladoC;
    }
    override calcularPerimetro(): number {
        return this.ladoA + this.ladoB + this.ladoC
    }
}

export class TrianguloEquilatero extends TrianguloEscaleno {    
    constructor(nombre:string, ladoA:number, ladoB:number, ladoC:number){
        super(nombre, ladoA, ladoB, ladoC)
    }
}

Now this is where I get the problem, home.page.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent } from '@ionic/angular/standalone';
import { CirculoComponent } from "../modelo/circulo/circulo.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  imports: [IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, CirculoComponent], <- there
  standalone: true,
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor() {}
}


imports: [IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, CirculoComponent], <- that's what is giving me the problem, which is this:

Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.(-992012)

I also think that figura-geometrica.ts is unnecessary, but that's how my teacher has done it, but with an easier example.

Would be great if you can take some time to reproduce the issue in StackBlitz. Thanks.

I don't know what that is but I'll try @Yong Shun

Is this good? link


You need to add the IonInput, IonItem, and IonList components to the imports array for CirculoComponent.

import { IonInput, IonItem, IonList } from '@ionic/angular/standalone';

@Component({
  ...,
  imports: [IonInput, IonItem, IonList],
})
export class CirculoComponent extends Circulo implements OnInit {
  ...
}


The arguments in the constructor of a component are dependency injectors. For your scenario, you need to add/register the Injection Token for nombre and radio into the providers either for the component or the root application/module. Next, use the @Inject() decorator to get the value from DI.

import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonInput, IonItem, IonList } from '@ionic/angular/standalone';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-circulo',
  templateUrl: './circulo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./circulo.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonInput, IonItem, IonList],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'nombre', useValue: 'test' },
    { provide: 'radio', useValue: 1 },
  ],
})
export class CirculoComponent extends Circulo implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject('nombre') nombre: string,
    @Inject('radio') radio: number
  ) {
    super(nombre, radio);
    this.radio = radio;
  }
}

For adding the injection token to the root application:
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    ...,
    { provide: 'nombre', useValue: 'test' },
    { provide: 'radio', useValue: 1 },
  ],
});

Demo @ StackBlitz
